# Timing related on 2000 Ford Excursion 6.8 Liter V10

Tags: ford, timing, cylinder-head

Kind of a lengthy question. I had to pull the cylinder heads in order to repair exhaust manifold bolts that were broken. Unfortunately, I was not able to do it from the wheel wells. Before starting the disassembly process, I went to position TDC, but after a partial turn, the engine would not rotate.

Being as I was all ready annoyed and not in a good mood that I was going to have to this repair the "hard" way, I didn't even think to put the tranny into neutral. I just ended up carefully marking and photographing everything so I could take it off as is and put it right back on. This would have worked, but after successfully fixing the passenger side head, I moved onto the driver side head.

Long story short due to a tool failing on me, I damaged the head and an now forced to buy a new head. I am trying to decide if I should manually rotate the cam to exactly match the old one and remount it that way or if I should just rotate the engine to TDC.

The problem is I can't rotate the engine counter clockwise, like the manual specifies since the crankshaft bolt is off and won't be re-tightened until I am done. I could rotate the engine clockwise without tightening the bolt too much, but I am concerned that I may damage the engine by doing this. Does anyone qualified mechanic out there know if this can damage the side I have all ready completed?  Any thoughts on this dilemma would be appreciated.

Comment: couple questions.  Cam in block, or SOHC/DOHC?  Do you currently have both heads off/1 head off, both heads on?  You will need to get it to TDC at some point to verify everything is lined up.  If you can think you can get it right, get it together, spin the engine over to TDC and see if it lines up.  If it is a tooth off, make adjustments.  This is risky if it is an interference engine.